# Реактивная передача данных между компонентами vue

Tags: vue.js, frontend

```
<st-tabs>
  <st-tabs-switcher to="tab1">Switch</st-tabs-switcher> 
  <st-tabs-switcher to="tab2">Switch 2</st-tabs-switcher> 

  <st-tabs-item index="tab1">TAB 1</st-tabs-item>
  <st-tabs-item index="tab2">TAB 2</st-tabs-item>
</st-tabs>
```

При клике на  его индекс из 'to' передается родителю  и сохраняется в переменной activeTab

Как связать реактивно activeTab из  в  (нужно чтобы забиндить класс active в st-tabs-switcher)

На данный момент **st-tabs-switcher импортирует функцию-обработки клика через provide/inject из st-tabs**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался -> https://medium.com/@znck/provide-inject-in-vue-2-2-b6473a7f7816

> Примечание: привязки provide и inject НЕ реактивны. Это сделано
>   намеренно. Тем не менее, если вы передаёте вниз отслеживаемый объект,
>   свойства на этом объекте остаются реактивными.
>   https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject